# PDF and Titanium SDK

Tags: pdf, titanium

I'm trying to make a app which is able to display PDFs. It should be possible to click web links within the document and dynamically load new PDFs into the app.

The file download and REST/JSON communication shouldn't be a problem but the PDF part looks kinda hard. Is there a way to display PDFs via the Appcelerator Titanium SDK?

This is app is targeting the iPad and iPhone.

Comment: you can show pdf files with url using WebView

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am trying to do this right now? I am using a WebView that loads a PDF directly, but the hyperlinks are not clickable

Comment: Nope, I' looking in native development and there are libraries like https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit - but we're currently reevaluting how we want to implement the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can show pdf files using [Titanium.UI.WebView](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.0/Titanium.UI.WebView)

Comment: I need to make weblinks within the PDF still clickable.